# Google Map Navigation Has Wrong Size

Tags: css, google-maps

**Update:** This is actually a current bug in Google Maps which has now already been reported.

---

It worked in the beginning, but since some (recent) update, the zoom icons in the Google Map on https://www.lookr.com/map do not fit into their original size anymore:

[image]

Do you know how this can be fixed? I tried to reset few CSS options on the `<button>` element (`height:auto` , `line-height:1em`) but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
.gmnoprint button {
    background: #fff !important;
}
```

or adjust min-height of that button

```
.gmnoprint button {
     min-height: 27px !important;
 }
```

Comment: Actually, the best solution is to set `min-height` to `0` (the height might change in the future)

Comment: This has the potential to break UI map controls across different versions of the product. Let's not forget [SO] is not a *fix-this-for-me-free-of-charge* website, but rather a *how-to-fix-this-type-of-problem-in-principle*. The above is a hack that will stop working and start creating problems the second the bug is updated/fixed by product publisher. So the proper action here is: downgrade to latest working version, report the bug to product publisher and wait for a fix before upgrading again.

Comment: Agreed with the above. And to @SimonFerndriger 1) Check that **your** CSS doesn't create this issue before *hacking around* as suggested here 2) Learn about versioning and how to load the *release* version of the API & test your code against various API versions to know where the problem comes from.

Comment: Thank you for your concerns, with which I would agree in general. BUT, setting the min-height for a button is a legid thing to do. So unsetting it for Google Maps (to the default value 0) is IMHO a legid thing to do as well - you cannot expect from a third party to consider all possible default style sheets, otherwise this would be a huge overhead. But I would actually suggest to use an iFrame for the map instead which would avoid this type of problem in general.

Comment: You are right, however, about reporting this to Google Maps - I will do that. Thank you for pointing this out.